# Mysql select query for multiple value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am writing a query like:

```
select * 
from table 
where cityid=2
```

but the problem is in my database cityid is stored as (1,2,3) for multiple cities
This query does not give me the desired result.

Comment: Is your value literally stored with parentheses around it, such as `(1,2,3)`, or is it stored without them such as `1,2,3`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this : if **val** is your parameter

```
Select 
*
from table 
where cityId like 'val,%' 
or cityId like '%,val,%' 
or cityId like '%,val'
```

Comment: This would also match `(11,12,13)` with `1`, `2` and `3`.

Comment: how?? it wont, please go through the query a bit minutely

Comment: h2oooooo U highlight a very good point, thank you very much...but fortunately for now I have only 1,2,3,4 but I should think about that.

Comment: @SashiKant If `val` is `1`, and `cityId` is `(11,12,13)` then `1,` would be found (`11,` includes the string `1,`).

Comment: @h2ooooooo: how it will be searched, since the wild character search is only from one side

Comment: @SashiKant You're right - I've completely misread your query. Just make sure that you include `(` and `)` in the first and last (as I think OP uses that). Sorry about the misunderstanding!

Comment: @h2ooooooo: no issues mate

Answer (score 1):

You could use MySQL's [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET(2, cityid) > 0;
```

However, I would actually recommend that you change your table's schema to *not* store multiple associations in a single cell. You could accomplish this with a second table that maps the relationships (think `create table table_cities (table_id int, city_id int);`) and then use a `join` to pull the values:

```
SELECT
    t.*
FROM
    table t
    JOIN table_cities tc
        ON t.id = tc.table_id
WHERE
    tc.city_id = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understood your requirement correctly. Based on my understanding, try this:

```sql
select * from table where cityid like '%,2,%';
```